# Use AR to Identify objects

Tags: model, 3d, augmented-reality

I have some parts that I have 3D models for and would like to use ar to look at the part and then tell me what the part number is and maybe some some info about it. The parts are all unique shapes. Is this something that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, anything is possible but you really need to be a little more clear about what you're asking. About what technologies you plan to use, what language, ect...

No matter what route you choose, ultimately your AR will first have to be programmed to understand some parameters about each part in order to identify them. Like people, AR weren't born knowing. ;)